# Neo4j: Best way to batch relate nodes using Cypher?

Tags: neo4j

When I run a script that tries to batch merge all nodes a certain types, I am getting some weird performance results.

When merging 2 collections of nodes (~42k) and (~26k), the performance is nice and fast.
But when I merge (~42) and (5), performance DRAMATICALLY degrades.  I'm batching the ParentNodes (so (~42k) split up in batches of 500.  **Why does performance drop when I'm, essentially, merging less nodes (when the batch set is the same, but the source of the batch set is high and the target set is low)?**

### Relation Query:

```
MATCH (s:ContactPlayer)   
WHERE  has(s.ContactPrefixTypeId)    
WITH  collect(s) AS allP   
WITH  allP[7000..7500] as rangedP   
FOREACH  (parent in rangedP  |  
    MERGE (child:ContactPrefixType 
            {ContactPrefixTypeId:parent.ContactPrefixTypeId}
          )  
    MERGE (child)-[r:CONTACTPLAYER]->(parent)  
    SET r.ContactPlayerId = parent.ContactPlayerId ,      
        r.ContactPrefixTypeId = child.ContactPrefixTypeId  )
```

### Performance Results:

Process Starting

Starting to insert Contact items
[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++]

---

- Total time for 42149 Contact items: 19176.87ms
- Average time per batch (500): 213.4ms
- Longest batch time: 663ms

Starting to insert ContactPlayer items
[++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++]

---

- Total time for 27970 ContactPlayer items: 9419.2106ms
- Average time per batch (500): 167.75ms
- Longest batch time: 689ms

Starting to relate Contact to ContactPlayer
[++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++]

---

- Total time taken to relate Contact to ContactPlayer: 7907.4877ms
- Average time per batch (500): 141.151517857143ms
- Longest batch time: 883.0918ms for Batch number: 0

Starting to insert ContactPrefixType items
[+]

---

- Total time for 5 ContactPrefixType items: 22.0737ms
- Average time per batch (500): 22ms
- Longest batch time: 22ms

Already inserted data for Contact.

Starting to relate ContactPrefixType to Contact
[+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
++++++]

---

- Total time taken to relate ContactPrefixType to Contact: 376540.8309ms
- Average time per batch (500): 4429.78643647059ms
- Longest batch time: 14263.1843ms for Batch number: 63

Comment: hmm.. I'm starting to think it has to do with a 1:1 relationship in the (~42k) -> (~26k) query and the 1:many relationship in the other query... I'm not sure how to go about optimizing this, other than switching the source to be the smallest of the two collection sets.  Is there a way to enforce some kind of Distinct mechanism?

Comment: How "many" on average is the 1:many ?

Comment: 5 prefix type id's split across 42k items.  Highest relationship ratio is: 1:41275 (where the contactprefixttypeid = 1).  Others encompass the remainder.  I could try doing nested batches.  one batch for each contactprefixtypeid and batch the contacts list by range?

Comment: I would use RANGE(X,Y) but sometimes the parent node doesn't have the property I'm trying to match, which would end up creating a bunch of nodes with just that property instead of matching 0 and skipping

Answer (score 0):

Can you pass the ids in as parameters rather than fetch them from the graph? The query could look like

```
MATCH (s:ContactPlayer {ContactPrefixTypeId:{cptid})
MERGE (c:ContactPrefixType {ContactPrefixTypeId:{cptid})
MERGE c-[:CONTACT_PLAYER]->s
```

If you use the REST API Cypher resource, I think the entity should look something like

```
{
    "query":...,
    "params": {
        "cptid":id1
    }
}
```

If you use the transactional endpoint, it should look something like this. You control transaction size by the number of statements in each call, and also by the number of calls before you commit. More [here](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html).

```
{
    "statements":[
        "statement":...,
        "parameters": {
            "cptid":id1
        },
        "statement":...,
        "parameters": {
            "cptid":id2
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That's a really interesting idea. I thought I already tried that but I'll try it again and see if I can get it to work. I'll post some number backs here for comparison.

Comment: I'm going to start working on this in a couple of hours. Quick question: If I don't set a unique constraint on the nodes, would it create a node if I specify `MERGE (c:Node {SomePropertyId : {arrayIds})`?  I've gotten some weird results before using MERGE (where nodes with ID's would be created and I ended up with duplicate ID nodes - until I specified the unique constraint)

Comment: Ok, so this doesn't seem to work:

`MATCH (parent:Contact {ContactPrefixTypeId : {propIdArray}})
MERGE  (child:ContactPrefixType {ContactPrefixTypeId : {propIdArray}})
MERGE  (child)-[r:CONTACT]->(parent)`

No Relationships get created at all even thought I can verify that those items exist in the database.  The propIdArray is an array with 5 items (because I'm sending in the distinct values - 1-5) `[1,2,3,4,5]`

Comment: `MATCH (c:Contact {ContactPrefixTypeId: [1,2,3,4,5]}) return c limit 10`  returns 0 results, but `MATCH (c:Contact {ContactPrefixTypeId: 1}) return c limit 10` returns 10.  I think it expects that to be an array, and isn't actually grabbing items that are in that array.

Comment: My bad, I was thinking of parameter maps but they only work with `CREATE`. I've edited my answer. I don't know if this is the best way (perhaps your db is embedded?), the main point is to provide values as parameters rather than reading them in chunks from the graph, or to create the relationships at the same time you create the nodes.

Comment: Is there a way to do an optional match and if that match returns results, set the values on the relationship - otherwise CREATE the relationship?  I'm wondering if that would be any faster than a merge.

Answer (score 0):

So far, the best I could come up with is the following (and it's a hack, specific to my environment):

If / Else condition:

`If childrenNodes.count() < 200` -> assume they are type identifiers for the parent... i.e. `ContactPrefixType`

Else assume it is a matrix for relating multiple item types together (i.e. ContactAddress)

`If childNodes < 200`

```
MATCH (parent:{parentLabel}), 
(child:{childLabel} {{childLabelIdProperty}:parent.{parentRelationProperty}})
CREATE child-[r:{relationshipLabel}]->parent
```

This  takes about 3-5 seconds to complete per relationship type

`Else`

```
MATCH (child:{childLabel}), 
(parent:{parentLabel} {{parentPropertyField : child.{childLabelIdProperty}})
WITH collect(parent) as parentCollection, child
WITH parentCollection[{batchStart}..{batchEnd}] as coll, child
FOREACH (parent in coll | 
CREATE child-[r:{relationshipLabel}]-parent )
```

I'm not sure this is the most efficient way of doing this, but after trying MANY different options, this seems to be the fastest.

Stats:

1. insert 225,018 nodes with 2,070,977 properties
2. create 464,606 relationships

Total: 331 seconds.

Because this is a straight import and I'm not dealing with updates yet, I assume that all the relationships are correct and don't need to worry about invalid data... however, I will try to set properties to the relationship type so as to be able to perform cleanup functions later (i.e. store the parent and child Id's in the relationship type as properties for later reference)

If anyone can improve on this, I would love it.