# How to improve performance for massive MERGE insert?

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to insert data from my SQL db into Neo4J. I have a CSV file where every row generates 4-5 entities and some relations between them. Entities might be duplicate between rows and I want to force uniqueness.

What I currently do is:

- create constraints for each label to force uniqueness.
- iterate the CSV:

  - start transaction
  - create merge statements for the entities
  - create merge statements for the relations
  - commit transaction

I got bad results. Then I tried to commit the transaction every X rows (X was 100, 500, 1000 and 5000). It's better now but I still have 2 problems:

- it's slow. on average around 1-1.5 seconds per 100 rows. (row = 4-5 entities and 4-5 relations).
- it's getting worse as I keep adding data. I usually start with 400-500 ms per 100 rows and after ~5000 rows I'm at ~4-5 seconds per 100 rows.

From what I know, my constraint also creates an index for that field. That's the field that is used when I create the new node with MERGE. Any chance it doesn't use the index?

What's the best practice for improving performance? I saw BatchInserter but wasn't sure if I can use it with MERGE operations.

Thanks

Comment: I'm dealing with this exact same issue. Check out some of my SO questions to see things I've tried. I'm going to try filtering IDs  so that I can batch with 1 match and 1 merge.

Comment: filtering by id's as recommended in this so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102181/neo4j-best-way-to-batch-relate-nodes-using-cypher/22116658?noredirect=1#22116658  did not work.

Comment: What driver are you using to programmatically generate the insert statements off of your CSV?

Comment: Do you need MERGE?  I found that CREATE is order of magnitude faster and causes less db hits.  Try running a small query using PROFILE; first with MERGE and then with CREATE to see if it makes a difference for you.